# Validation for a certain action in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise, passwords

In my current ROR project I am using devise pluing for validation. In my change password form validation, I am using the following code in the `user` model

```
validates_presence_of :password, :password_confirmation
```

But I wants to validate is only for an action. I have a function in my user controller named `update_password`. I found the that I can assign the action as follows:

```
validates_presence_of :password, :password_confirmation, :on => :update_password
```

But its not working. Even if the password and password confirmation fields are empty, the form is submitted. Can anyone help me to solve how to set the validation only for a particular action. Will be a great help

Thanks a lot

Comment: `:on` option accepts values `:create` or `:update`, not `:update_password`

Comment: so how can I set `update_password` to it

Comment: `:on` option is not for "controller context", but "action on the model". You can set an instance variable to set context from controller, and test it with `:if` option

Answer (score 2):

You can use :validatable option implemented in devise.
Just add to your model

```
devise :validatable
```

And set validation options in your `config/initializers/devise.rb` file

```
# ==> Configuration for :validatable
# Range for password length. Default is 6..128.
config.password_length = 6..128

# Email regex used to validate email formats. It simply asserts that
# an one (and only one) @ exists in the given string. This is mainly
# to give user feedback and not to assert the e-mail validity.
config.email_regexp = /\A[^@]+@[^@]+\z/
```

Another way is to use your own regexp validations. You can add to your model

```
validates :password, :format => { :with => /\A[a-zA-Z]+\z/, :message => "Only letters allowed" }
```

After that you can call @user.valid? in your controller to check that your user instance is correct.

There are many different ways to validate your model. 
You can read more about validation and ActiveRecord callbacks in guides: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations_callbacks.html

Answer (score 0):

If you're using devise, there's no need to check for that. It's handle for you by default.

Comment: Thanks but how can I configure? I've enabled validatable, but its not working. Following is the way I've added 'em `  devise  :database_authenticatable, 
          :rememberable,   
          :trackable,                  :validatable,    
          :recoverable`

Comment: You might need to restart your rails server for the changes in devise to take place. Remember to run any migrations too.